# How to wire up an editor to the location cursor icons?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I have built a graphical editor as an Eclipse plugin. Users may zoom into and pan about the graphical image.

I would like to employ the Back and Forward arrow icons in the Eclipse icon bar to step back and forth through the graphical image, in a similar manner to what is already possible in textual editors. All of my references go quiet on this subject

All clues or better references are most welcome.

M.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a RetargetAction

See an example at
http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/rcp_actions.htm

(I haven't done this myself, but it sounds right...)

See also http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_retarget.htm